# Is there a function to convert a Twitter API created_at date into the correct format for ColdFusion 8+?

Tags: date, coldfusion, twitter

The Twitter API spits back dates (created_at) from api.twitter.com with JSON format in the following format:

"Fri Dec 10 17:12:00 +0000 2010" (<-- notice the year is at the end)

ColdFusion 9 doesn't seem to like this format and gives an error.

I tried various built-in ColdFusion date functions, to no avail. And I couldn't find anything useful on cflib.org. So, does anyone have a function for this already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could easily treat that string as a space-delimited list and compose a more friendly string. Since Arrays are faster than lists, I'll get it into an array as fast as possible and then work from that.

```
public string function getSaneTwitterDate(strDateIn) output="false"{
  var arrOrigDate = listToArray(strDateIn, ' ');
  var strNewDate = arrOrigDate[2] & ' ' & arrOrigDate[3] & ' ' & arrOrigDate[6];
  return dateFormat(strNewDate, 'yyyy-mm-dd');
}
```

This doesn't account for the time offset or include time information, but it would be easy to add.

Comment: so simple when you put it that way :D  I modified it slightly by appending "& ' ' & arrOrigDate[4]" to the end of the return value so that it includes the time as well... thanks Adam!

Comment: Updated it to correctly parse Twitter dates from the Search API

`public string function getSaneTwitterDate(strDateIn) output="false"{
   var arrOrigDate = listToArray(arguments.strDateIn, ' ');
   var strNewDate = arrOrigDate[2] & ' ' & arrOrigDate[3] & ' ';

   // from api.twitter.com
   if ( IsNumeric(arrOrigDate[3]) ) {
    strNewDate &= arrOrigDate[6];
  return dateFormat(strNewDate, 'yyyy-mm-dd') & ' ' & arrOrigDate[4];
   // from search.twitter.com
   } else {
    strNewDate &= arrOrigDate[4];
  return dateFormat(strNewDate, 'yyyy-mm-dd') & ' ' & arrOrigDate[5];
   }
 }`

Answer (score 2):

try http://pastebin.com/GuXu8Dy1

```
<cfscript>
function twitterDate(date,offset) {
    var retDate = listtoarray(date, " ");
    var thisDay = retDate[1];
    var thisMonth = retDate[2];
    var thisDate = retDate[3];
    var thisTime = timeformat(retDate[4], "h:mm tt");
    var thisYear = retDate[6];
    var thisReturn = "";
    var thisFormat = "#thisMonth#, #thisDate# #thisYear#";

    thisFormat = dateformat(thisFormat, "m/d/yy") & " " & thisTime;
    thisFormat = dateadd("s", offset, thisFormat);
    thisFormat = dateadd("h", 1, thisFormat);

    longFormat = dateformat(thisFormat, "yyyy-mm-dd") & " " & timeformat(thisFormat, "HH:mm:ss");

    thisReturn = longFormat;
    return thisReturn;
}
</cfscript>
```

Comment: Seriously? You couldn't be bothered to copy and paste the code into your answer?

Comment: it was already in pastebin since i answered him on twitter.  apologies for trying to help others who might be searching in the future and come here.

Comment: The point is, linkrot happens. If, for some reason, that link changes or goes away, this answer has absolutely *no* value. Better to copy (or excerpt) the information at the destination and source it with a link.

Comment: Why is there an offset argument in the function?

Answer (score 2):

```
<cffunction name="parseTwitterDateFormat" output="false" returntype="String" hint="I return a date in a useable date format.">
    <cfargument name="twitterDate" required="true" type="string" hint="The Twitter date." />

    <cfset var formatter = CreateObject("java", "java.text.SimpleDateFormat").init("EEE MMM d kk:mm:ss Z yyyy") />
    <cfset formatter.setLenient(true) />

    <cfreturn formatter.parse(arguments.twitterDate) />
</cffunction>
```

Credit goes to Matt Gifford's monkeyTweet library https://github.com/coldfumonkeh/monkehTweets

Comment: What is cool about `setLenient(true)` is that causes the formatter to automatically adjust invalid dates like "Feb 30 2010" to a valid one ie "Mar 2 2010". If you want more strict parsing, just set it to `false`.